# How can I attribute schema's privileges to a role?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, database-administration

Consider this case, in an Oracle database, there are some privileges attributed to an HR schema for example; i have created a role developer_user and i want to attribute HR's privileges to this role.What query should I try ? Thanks in advance.

I tried this but it didn't pay off :

SQL> GRANT all privileges from dba_sys_privs to developer_user where grantee='HR' ;

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What do you mean that a privilege is "attributed to an HR schema".  Do you want to grant a role all of the system privileges that have been granted to HR?  Which would not allow users with the role to have any access to the objects in the HR schema.  But would, for example, potentially allow the user to create new objects in their local schema.  Or do you want to grant the role access to objects in the HR schema?  Or something else?

Comment: If you want to give the developer access to the HR schema and inherit all permissions, consider proxy authentication: it's much simpler to maintain over time than updating a flock of roles. See here for example: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2021/10/15/shared-application-accounts-revisited/

Comment: Thanks for answering Mr. Cave, I mean, for example, I connected to the user HR, basically, this user has privileges, then I created a role named developer_user and I want to attribute the HR privileges to this role in one command.

Comment: Like for example, HR user has " connect and resource " as privileges, how can I attribute these privileges to the developer, except this solution : Grant connect , resource to developer_user ;